# Insert data into custom table using resource model and block class

Tags: magento, mvvm, magento2

i am new in magento2. i have retrieve records from table and showed in grid but now i am trying to Insert/data in a custom table from a form but not getting any help. Can you pls guide me how can i Insert data in custom table using block class and resource model etc. i mean standard way to insert data.

Here is block class

```
class Insert extends Template
{
    private $collectionFactory;
    public $successMessage=null;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookName');
        $author = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookAuthor');
        $description = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookDescription');
        $model = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $model->load($name);
        $model->load($author);
        $model->load($description);*/
        $input = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $model->setData($input);        
        $model->save(); 
        $successMessage="Saved Successfully!";
    }
}
```

-----------These are model classes---------------

```
class Book extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Vendor\BooksModule\Model\ResourceModel\Book::class);
    }
}


class Book extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor_BooksModule_Book', 'id');
    }
}
```

----------------This is resource model-----------------

```
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("Vendor\BooksModule\Model\Book","Vendor\BooksModule\Model\ResourceModel\Book");
    }
}
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, need to create a customer module. some instruction here https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html

After creating a custom module you need a create your custom table. and resource model using that link. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

After creating a table and model you can save data inside a block. Inside block can data using getParam. But want to change like that.

```
public function execute()
{
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookName');
    $author = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookAuthor');
    $description = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bookDescription');
    $model = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $model = $model->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('bookName', $name)->addFieldToFilter('bookAuthor', $author)->addFieldToFilter('bookDescription', $description);
    $input = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    $model->setData($input);
    $model->save();
    $successMessage="Saved Successfully!";
}
```

We can collection only load with id. that is wrong you done. When use setData you also want to add attribute name. check and change that.

Comment: thank you for your help but its not working. Secondly i am trying to insert a new record how can we do that?

Comment: above steps i followed already all. just now trying to save data from a form to database then after this edit and delete a record from collection grid